# Xamarin Android change accessibility focus

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, focus, accessibility

In Android Studio, using Java, to set the accessibility focus on a certain view after, for example, pressing a button, you have to do `myview.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.WINDOWS_CHANGE_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED)`. In Xamaring, using C#, the closest thing that I found is `myview.SendAccessibilityEvent(EventTypes.ViewAccessibilityFocused);` but it doesn't work that good, infact, it only read out the `myview` accessibility name, without actually setting the focus on that, the focus remain on the button pressed. I also tried `myview.SendAccessibilityEvent(EventTypes.ViewFocused);` but it doesn't work either.

Another thing that I found is `myview.SendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityEvent.WindowsChangeAccessibilityFocused);` but I got an error saying `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.Views.Accessibility.WindowsChange' to 'Android.Views.Accessibility.AccessibilityEvent'` even if it is said that `SendAccessibilityEventUnchecked` takes an `AccessibilityEvent` as argument.

Any idea on how to solve?
Or any idea on how to set the accessibility focus to a certain view after some event? 
(Note if needed, I am just testing it on Android native, than I will need to use that in a Forms project using Dependency Service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the right way to achieve that should be `myview.SendAccessibilityEvent(EventTypes.ViewHoverEnter)` that has the same integer value of the Android value `WINDOWS_CHANGE_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED`.

Another way is to do `myview.SendAccessibilityEvent((EventTypes) (int) WindowsChange.AccessibilityFocused)` so you have to do a double cast, `int` and `EventTypes`, on `WindowsChange.AccessibilityFocused` because `WindowsChange` is a different enum from `EventTypes`.

I leave the github issue that I opened where I got these answers [git issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4322).

Answer (score 0):

WINDOWS_CHANGE_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED is a sub type for [TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent#TYPE_WINDOWS_CHANGED), which should only be dispatched by the system. And the accessibility focus won't be changed by sending accessibility event.

Actually, send accessibility event triggers Accessibility Service, and you can change the accessibility focus in the service's onAccessibilityEvent method with:

```
public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
{
   //you can use event type and source node to see if the event is sent by you
    AccessibilityNodeInfo sourceNode = e.Source;
    AccessibilityNodeInfo targetNode = sourceNode.FocusSearch(FocusSearchDirection.Down);
    targetNode.PerformAction(Android.Views.Accessibility.Action.AccessibilityFocus);
}
```

See more information about Accessibility Focus and Input Focus [here](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo?hl=en#public-methods).